# COPY a csv file with 108 column into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, error-handling

I have a csv file with 108 columns which i try to import in my postgresql table. It is obvious that I don't want to specify every columns in my CREATE TABLE statement. But when I enter 
\COPY 'table_name' FROM 'directory' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER; this error message shows up: "ERROR: Extra Data after Last Expected Column". When having a few columns I know how to fix this problem but, like I said, i don't want to specified the entire 108 columns. By the way my table does contain any columns at all. Any help on how I could do that? Thx !

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with problems like this, I often cheat. Plenty of tools exist online for converting CSV to SQL, https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm being one of them.

Copy/paste your CSV, copy/paste the generated SQL. Not the most elegant solution, although will work as a one-off situation.

Now, if you're looking to repeat this process regularly (automated I hope), then Python may be a interesting language to explore to quickly write a script to do this for you, then schedule it at a CRON job or whatever method you prefer for invoking it automatically with the correct input (CSV file).

Please feel free to let me know if I've misunderstood your original question, or if I can provide any more help give me a shout and I'll do my best!